# What's the difference between Django-registration and the built-in Django authentication system?

Tags: django, authentication

I was wondering what are the differences between these apps, since they provide the same functionality and Django-registration is written by the creator of Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not the same at all. Django's built in authentication deals with login and permissions. Django-registration deals with registration, ie the ability for people to sign up for accounts.

Comment: I got confused while looking at the code and seeing similar methods, but now I understand the difference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @alex you should mark this answer and the solution to your problem/question